# it seems that there is no need to use "also" here, is my understanding right?

Tags: meaning

this [post](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/architecture.html) says

> The noun architecture can be countable or uncountable.
>
> In more general, commonly used, contexts, the plural form will also be architecture.

The post didn't mention other form before, it seems that there is no need to use "also" here, is my understanding right?

Comment: By the way, the Wordhippo article is wrong. The plural of "architecture" is "architectures", in all contexts. The author is confused about uncountable nouns. When we treat a noun as having an uncountable meaning, we just don't use the plural form.

Answer (score 1):

The writer is using the word **also** to say that the plural of the word **architecture** will be the same as the singular.

Except in exceptional cases, the word will remain **architecture** rather than **architectures**.

The **also** is being used naturally to compare the plural with the singular. The **also** could be omitted without changing the sense but its use is idiomatic.